# Show pictures from a folder

Tags: php, path

i have an admin panel to show all the clients requests.how can i show the pictures from a folder if the page "admin.php" and the folder are not in
the admin panel is in : WWW.URL.com/WP-admin/administration/admin.php
and the folder is in : WWW.URL.com/upload

```
$directory = '??';
```

what to put in the variable `$directory` to fetch the folder picture ?

Answer (score 0):

have to use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] in directory.
 Try this code.

```
$directory = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."upload";
$images = glob($directory ."*.png");
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br />';
}
```

Comment: thank you . i receive this error message : No such file or directory in /srv/disk5/2035382/www/olexim.co.nf/wp-admin/administration/Propositions.ph ... i don't have acces to the server how can i edit the engine rewrite ?

Comment: What is your path and your project path?

Comment: the project path : http://olexim.co.nf/  .   the admin page : http://olexim.co.nf/wp-admin/administration/Propositions.php . the image folder : olexim.co.nf/upload

Comment: Use this `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] `  replace `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Comment: sorry everybody but not a solution yet